# Reversing the letters in words in a String

Tags: string, java-8

I have coded the following solution, and it works, except for when there is punctuation. I was wondering if there are O(1) space complexity and O(length of string) time complexity solutions, without using reverse() method, or anything similar that makes this task too easy. Any answer that can also handle punctuation correctly would be great.

Example:

Given string: "I love chocolate"

Return string should be: "I evol etalocohc"

For clarity, when I say handle punctuation correctly, I mean punctuation should not move around.

```
 // reverse the letters of every word in a sentence (string), and return the result

 public static String reverse(String x)
 {
     String[] str = x.split(" ");

     StringBuilder rev = new StringBuilder("");

     for (int i = 0; i < str.length; i++)
     {
         for (int s = str[i].length()-1; s >= 0; s--)
         {
             rev.append(str[i].charAt(s));
         }
         rev.append(" ");
     }

     return rev.toString();
 }
```

Here is my output for some tests of mine:

```
     public static void main(String[] args)
     {
         System.out.println(reverse("I love chocolate"));//this passes
         System.out.println(reverse("Geeks for Geeks"));//this passes
         System.out.println(reverse("You, are awesome"));//not handling puncutation mark correctly, gives me ",uoY era emosewa", instead of "uoY, era emosewa"
         System.out.println(reverse("Geeks! for Geeks."));//not handling puncutation marks correctly, gives me "!skeeG rof .skeeG", instead of "skeeG! rof skeeG."
     }
```

Comment: Java strings are immutable, if your result is going to be the length of the length of the string, space complexity can't be less than O(n).

Comment: @apokryfos I think he means no additional space beyond the original string.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yes that's what i mean too, you can't modify the original string, you need to make new string of the same length.

Comment: @apokryfos But what about a `StringBuilder` ?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen that still can't modify the original string as far as i know. If you start off with a stringbuilder instead of a string that's a different story though.

Comment: @apokryfos That is what I was thinking, regarding space complexity. But what about time complexity, can we get O(N). N being the length of the string, rather than quadratic, like my current solution.

Comment: Your solution isn't quadratic. If you loop over each character of each word you're going over `n` characters total. Not `n^2` characters. I guess to handle punctuation you need to split on any non-word character instead of just spaces.

Comment: @apokryfos Hmmm, that makes sense, and I guess I'm better off then. I am assuming to handle punctuation, I would need to use some sort of regex? I am totally unfamiliar with Java regex.

Answer (score 1):

This would probably work with the punctuation:

```
public static String reverse(String x)
{
     String[] str = x.split("\\W"); //Split on non-word characters.

     StringBuilder rev = new StringBuilder("");
     int currentPosition = 0;
     for (int i = 0; i < str.length; i++)
     {
         for (int s = str[i].length()-1; s >= 0; s--)
         {
             rev.append(str[i].charAt(s));
             currentPosition++;
         }
         while (currentPosition < x.length() && Character.toString(x.charAt(currentPosition)).matches("\\W")) 
            rev.append(x.charAt(currentPosition++)); //Add the actual character there.
     }

     return rev.toString();
 }
```

Haven't coded in Java in a while now so I know it's probably not best practices here.

Complexity is O(n) (space and time).

If you start off with a string builder you might be able to lower space complexity by using in-place character swaps instead of appending, but you'd need to preemptively find where all the non-word characters are.

Comment: “*but you'd need to preemptively find where all the non-word characters are*”—that’s exactly what you do with `x.split("\\W")` right in the first line. You are checking for non-word characters *again* in the loop.

Comment: @Holger I'm not claiming I'm not doing that. I'm just saying using a `StringBuilder` for in-place swaps will offer no time improvement, only space improvement.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an implementation which uses in-place reversing of words requiring only `O(1)` storage.  In addition, the reversing algorithm itself is `O(N)` with the length of the string.

The basic algorithm is to walk down the string until hitting a space.  Then, the `swap()` method is called to reverse that particular word in place.  It only needs at any moment one extra character.

This approach may not be as performant as the accepted answer due to its heavy use of `StringBuilder` manipulations.  But this might something to consider in an environment like an Android application where space is very precious.

```
 public static void swap(StringBuilder input, int start, int end) {
    for (int i=0; i <= (end - start) / 2; ++i) {
        char ch = input.charAt(start + i);
        input.setCharAt(start + i, input.charAt(end - i));
        input.setCharAt(end - i, ch);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("I love chocolate");

    int start = 0;
    int end = 0;

    while (true) {
        while (end <= sb.length() - 1 && sb.charAt(end) != ' ') {
            ++end;
        }
        swap(sb, start, end - 1);
        start = end + 1;
        end = start;
        if (end > sb.length() - 1) {
            break;
        }
    }

    System.out.println(sb);
}
```

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Comment: With only a very minor modification at `!= ' '` this would work with any non-word character as a delimiter.

Comment: @apokryfos Well ideally we'd like to account for any number of word boundaries, but my answer is more of an example.

Comment: @snr this is `O(n)` all characters are visited exactly twice.

Answer (score 1):

I just have made changes on your code, not additional methods or loops, just some variables and if conditions.

```
/* Soner - The methods reverse a string with preserving punctiations */
public static String reverse(String x) {
    String[] str = x.split(" ");
    boolean flag = false;
    int lastCharPosition;
    StringBuilder rev = new StringBuilder("");

    for (int i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        flag = false;
        lastCharPosition = str[i].length()-1;
        if (str[i].charAt(lastCharPosition) == '.' || str[i].charAt(lastCharPosition) == '!'
                || str[i].charAt(lastCharPosition) == ',') {  // you can add new punctiations
            flag = true;
            lastCharPosition = str[i].length()-2;
        }
        for (int s = lastCharPosition; s >= 0; s--) {
            rev.append(str[i].charAt(s));
        }
        if (flag) rev.append(str[i].charAt(lastCharPosition + 1));
        rev.append(" ");
    }

    return rev.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A compact solution is

```
public static String reverse(String x) {
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\w+").matcher(x);
    if(!m.find()) return x;
    StringBuffer target = new StringBuffer(x.length());
    do m.appendReplacement(target, new StringBuilder(m.group()).reverse().toString());
    while(m.find());
    return m.appendTail(target).toString();
}
```

The [`appendReplacement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendReplacement-java.lang.StringBuffer-java.lang.String-) loop + [`appendTail`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendTail-java.lang.StringBuffer-) on a `Matcher` is the manual equivalent of `String.replaceAll(regex)`, intended to support exactly such cases where the replacement is more complex than a simple string with placeholders, like reversing the found words.

Unfortunately, we have to use the outdated `StringBuffer` here, as the API is older than `StringBuilder`. [Java 9 is going to change that](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendReplacement-java.lang.StringBuilder-java.lang.String-).

A potentially more efficient alternative is

```
public static String reverse(String x) {
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\w+").matcher(x);
    if(!m.find()) return x;
    StringBuilder target = new StringBuilder(x.length());
    int last=0;
    do {
        int s = m.start(), e = m.end();
        target.append(x, last, s).append(new StringBuilder(e-s).append(x, s, e).reverse());
        last = e;
    }
    while(m.find());
    return target.append(x, last, x.length()).toString();
}
```

This uses `StringBuilder` throughout the operation and usese the feature to append partial character sequences, not creating intermediate strings for the match and replacement. It also elides the search for placeholders in the replacement, which `appendReplacement` does internally.

Comment: *finally* a good solution; using `StringBuilder#reverse` also takes care of surrogate pairs.

Comment: @Eugene There can be a big overhead to using regex vs. the base string functions.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: all shown solutions which handle punctuation generally (or at all) are using regex.